# Can I use one statment to get distinct rows from each column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/420819/3)

Is it possible to combine these four distinct queries into one statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) from `product` order by name;
SELECT DISTINCT (category) from `product` order by category;
SELECT DISTINCT (price) from `product` order by price;
SELECT DISTINCT (year) from `product` order by year;
```

I want to get distinct rows from each column and return the results in JSON format for a select box's options, but I don't know how to return results like the following without using four independent select statements:

```
NAME   
A
C
D
E
G

CATEGORY
Brainteaser
Doll
Outdoor

PRICE

20
22
25
30
34

YEAR

2008
2009
2010
```

TABLE:
   CREATE TABLE product
        (`ID` int, `name` varchar(1), `category` varchar(11), `price` int,`year`int)
    ;

```
INSERT INTO product
    (`ID`, `name`, `category`, `price`,`year`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'Outdoor', 25,2010),
    (2, 'A', 'Doll', 34,2009),
    (3, 'C', 'Doll', 25,2008),
    (4, 'D', 'Outdoor', 20,2010),
    (5, 'E', 'Brainteaser', 22,2010),
    (6, 'E', 'Brainteaser', 22,2009),
    (7, 'G', 'Brainteaser', 30,2009),
    (8, 'G', 'Brainteaser', 30,2009)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FIELDVALUE, 'NAME' FIELDNAME from `product` 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT (category) FIELDVALUE, 'CATEGORY' FIELDNAME from `product` 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT (price) FIELDVALUE, 'PRICE' FIELDNAME  from `product` 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT (year) FIELDVALUE, 'YEAR' FIELDNAME  from `product` ;
```

It gives an output as:

```
FIELDVALUE      FIELDNAME
A               NAME
C               NAME
D               NAME
E               NAME
G               NAME
Outdoor         CATEGORY
Doll            CATEGORY
Brainteaser     CATEGORY
25              PRICE
34              PRICE
20              PRICE
22              PRICE
30              PRICE
2010            YEAR
2009            YEAR
2008            YEAR
```